# How to receive a notification from AWS SQS when a new message is added to the queue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-sqs

I am trying to set up an SQS queue from AWS, my goal is

1. Receive notification from an sns topic which is basically coming from amazon marketplace.
2. When a new message comes in i need to notify my application that a new message is received along with the message or at least a notification that there is a new message.

Is there a way to achieve this? from documentation i could see that we can receive a message using the sdk, and i am using Node js, Express, [link to amazon sdk-javaScript for sqs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html). should i keep on checking the sqs with a time interval ? there should be a better way i believe.

Comment: You could simply add an SQS event trigger which would trigger a Lambda function and in the Lambda function add your code.

Comment: can i assign this SQS event trigger to only a lambda function or can it be used to call a url that i can provide. so that i can handle it in my application.

Comment: Not directly afaik. Your Lambda function could take data from the event payload and POST/GET the remote HTTP(S) endpoint. Or your Lambda function could publish to an SNS topic and you could subscribe your HTTP(S) endpoint to that SNS topic.

Comment: yup got it thanks.

Comment: Why not have SNS directly notify your application? Since you're using NodeJS I'm assuming that it's a web-app.

Comment: Why do you wish to use SQS? You can simply respond directly to the SNS notification by triggering a Lambda function. Can you change how you receive the notification (eg to SNS or SQS, or Lambda)?

Comment: Initially thought of handling the SNS from Amazon Market place directly in my application but needed guaranty that notification is handled (for application down times). so thought of SQS. but did not like the idea of application keep on checking for new messages in the SQS. So trying to implement SQS and lambda.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set up an Elastic Beanstalk worker-type env that hooks up to that SQS queue. When you create a worker-type beanstalk env (and you can choose Node there), you can specify which queue it consumes and what is the HTTP path that SQS will post the new messages to (an expressjs POST handler or something). It makes consuming the queue a bit easier, you either return 200 to destroy the message, or throw from that POST to put it back on the queue to retry or dead-letter it.